# How to store MySQL data safely?

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to keep your MySQL credentials private in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492192/what-is-the-best-way-to-keep-your-mysql-credentials-private-in-php)

I have a website with lots of .php files that connect to mysql database, and they run under different domains, so I have a **mysql_data.php** file (with different values for each domain) like:

```
define("MYSQL_HOST","localhost");
define("MYSQL_USERNAME","root");
define("MYSQL_PASSWORD","etc");
```

and then the other .php files use this info like:

```
require_once("mysql_data.php");

$mysql_host = MYSQL_HOST;
$mysql_database = MYSQL_DATABASE;
$mysql_user = MYSQL_USERNAME;
$mysql_password = MYSQL_PASSWORD;

$connection = @mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die(mysql_error());
$db = @mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

This works fine, except regarding security. One can easily access this mysql_data.php file (I guess). So what would be a safer way to store this data?
Thanks!

Comment: Do users have to log in to use the site?  If so you can use $_SESSION variables to validate login names.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use MySQL root account for web application.
2. If you have PHP installed correctly and there are no security issues on server - there is no way to get PHP file content from outside.
3. Go to [The New Boston](http://thenewboston.org) website and watch some tutorial videos about php and mysql.